# In Google Sheets, can I query DXY?

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried:

=importxml("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/DXY", "//span[@id='quote_val']/text()")

and a few other things, but so far no luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of `//span[@id='quote_val']/text()` from `https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/DXY`.

#### Issue and workaround:

When `=IMPORTXML("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/DXY","//*")` is put to a cell, I confirmed that an error of `Could not fetch url: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/DXY` occurs. But when I tested the URL using UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script, I confirmed that the HTML data can be retrieved.

In this answer, as a workaround, I would like to suggest to achieve your goal using a custom function using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Spreadsheet, and save it. When you use this script, please put `=SAMPLE("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/DXY")` to a cell. By this, the script is run and the value is retrieved.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const res = html.match(/<span id="quote_val">(.+?)<\/span>/);
  if (!res) throw new Error("Value cannot be retrieved.")
  return isNaN(res[1]) ? res[1] : Number(res[1]);
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)